# Stop execution of code when requiring another file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, require, execution

I have a file `foo.rb` that has the following:

```
class Foo
    def do_stuff
        puts "Doing stuff"
    end

    def do_other_stuff
        puts "Doing other stuff"
    end
end

f = Foo.new
f.do_stuff
```

I want require this file in another file `bar.rb` and access to the methods in the `Foo` class without executing the instructions in `foo.rb`.
Expecting to output just:

```
Doing other stuff
```

I tried the following in `bar.rb`:

```
require 'foo'

f = Foo.new
f.do_other_stuff
```

However, requiring the file executes the code of `foo.rb`, and my output is this:

```
Doing stuff
Doing other stuff
```

Is there a good way to get around this execution?

Comment: How are you going to get "access to the methods in the `Foo` class without executing the instructions in `foo.rb`" when the methods in the `Foo` class get defined by executing the instructions in `foo.rb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requiring a file will execute the code. I think its a bad design, what you are trying to achieve. However you can still circumvent it by putting the code in `if __FILE__ == $0` block:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
 f = Foo.new
 f.do_stuff
end
```

`if __FILE__ == $0` will make sure the code inside the block is executed only when run directly and not when required, as in your example.

Comment: @samalamma708 Your question implied that you cannot change `foo.rb`, and that you were looking for a solution by changing `bar.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to block the outputs, do something like this:

```
stdout_old = $stdout.dup
stderr_old = $stderr.dup
$stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
$stdout.reopen(IO::NULL)
require "foo"
$stdout.flush
$stderr.flush
$stdout.reopen(stdout_old)
$stderr.reopen(stderr_old)
```

Comment: Interesting, but borderline. The OP wants access to `Foo` "without executing the instructions in foo.rb". With your solution the instructions are still executed, though now they leave no trace, and that relies on `do stuff` doing nothing other than a `puts`. If `do_stuff` would send a man to Mars, he'd be on his (or her) way. You might add some words to address the question when `do_stuff` can be anything (assuming "foo.rb" cannot be altered).

Comment: @CarySwoveland I realized that, but took it loosely. You are right. But being strict, method definitions are also execution. And there are one-way trips to Mars, which are scary.

Answer (score 0):

> I want require this file in another file `bar.rb` and access to the methods in the `Foo` class without executing the instructions in `foo.rb`.

Since the methods in the `Foo` class are *defined* by executing the instructions in `foo.rb`, this is obviously non-sensical and impossible: either you want `Foo`, then you have to execute the instructions, or you don't execute the instructions, but then you don't get `Foo`.